# Space diagonals of a dodecahedron

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I have been studying on platonic solids for a while and figuring out properties of dodecahedron. A dodecahedron with sidelength $a$ has $60$ surface diagonals and $100$ space diagonals, $10$ being long, $30$ being medium, and $60$ being short. I have figured out length of long diagonal is $a\sqrt{1+\phi^{4}}$ and medium diagonal is $a\phi^{2}$ but I couldn't find the short diagonal.

Comment: Small quibble: you should use the term *regular* dodecahedron if you're referring to the geometric object with specific sidelengths and angles.

Comment: You are right sorry about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually are most of the way to getting the short space diagonals. Let A be any vertex of the regular dodecahedron and B be the opposite vertex. If C is any other vertex then $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with right angle at C because all vertices lie in a sphere with diameter $\overline{AB}$. If we choose C so that $\overline{AC}$ is a face diagonal whose length is $a\phi$ (diagonals of a regular pentagon with side length $a$), and if we use $a\sqrt{1+\phi^4}$ as the length of the hypotenuse, we are left with $a\sqrt{1-\phi^2+\phi^4}$ as the length of the short space diagonals.

If we plug in $\phi^2=1+\phi$ and $\phi^4=2+3\phi$ (shout-out to Fibonacci) we discover that in fact the short space diagonals measure $a\phi\sqrt2$ and the long ones simplify to $a\phi\sqrt3$, the ratios seeming as if we were dealing with squares and cubes rather than pentagons and dodecahedra. What gives?

The face diagonals of a regular dodecahedron have the property that if you select one from each of the twelve faces in the proper manner, you define the edges of a cube (see the drawing in [heropup's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4181412/248217)). Then your short space diagonals of the dodecahedron are face diagonals of the cubes, each edge of which measures $a\phi$, and the long space diagonals of the dodecahedron are space diagonals of the cubes.

Comment: İ missed the sphere right angle trick with seeing that its pretty easy thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

A regular dodecahedron can be placed in $\mathbb R^3$ such that the vertices are $$(\pm 1, 0, \pm \phi^2),$$ their circular permutations $(0, \pm \phi^2, \pm 1), (\pm \phi^2, \pm 1, 0)$, and the inscribed cube $(\pm \phi, \pm \phi, \pm \phi)$, where $\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio.  The circumradius is therefore $\phi \sqrt{3}$, and the dodecahedral edge length is simply $2$.  Then the face diagonals have length equal to the edge length of the cube, which is $2\phi$, the shortest interior diagonal between two vertices will be the distance between, for instance, $(-1, 0, \phi^2)$ and $(\phi^2, 1, 0)$, which is $2 \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{5}}$.  Alternatively, it can be computed as simply $\sqrt{2}$ times the length of the cube edge, i.e. $2 \sqrt{2} \phi$.  It is straightforward to compute all of the interior diagonal lengths and normalize these by the edge length, which I leave as an exercise.

I don't have time to create my own diagram, so I pulled one from [the Internet](https://www.software3d.com/5Dod.php).  This construction of the regular dodecahedron dates back to at least to the time of Euclid, as it appears in the *Elements*.

The ratio of the edge length of the cube to the edge length of the dodeachedron is $\phi$.

[image]